# Nested Foreach loop runs too many times - C#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have 2 `foreach` loops, 1 nested inside the other. There are 115 total items in 2 collections. What I'm wanting to do is have the first item from the first collection written to the console and then the first item from the second collection written to the console. Go back to the first collection and do the second item and so on.

I understand why the nested loop is running over and over, I just can't figure out how to achieve what I want to achieve.

```
var Titles = chromeDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.contentItem__contentWrapper h1"));
var Text = chromeDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.contentItem__contentWrapper p"));        

foreach (var title in Titles)
{
    string t = title.Text;
    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {t}");
    foreach (var text in Text)
    {
        string p = text.Text;
        Console.WriteLine($"Article Text: {p}");
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is `Text` in the inner `foreach`?

Comment: One of the two collections? `There are 115 total items in 2 collections`?

Comment: I'm not guessing - it seems pretty clear to me!

Comment: Now it's been put on hold as "off-topic". @RodneyWilson I apologise for this kind of behaviour - it's for this reason I don't post so much on SO any more.

Comment: @DavidG I'm not pointing fingers and it's a bit off-topic for this question, but I'm just fed up with trying to help people only to find them deleting their own questions a few minutes later feeling dejected for asking for help. I was a newb once, and I might not have asked the best questions had this site been around. Now it's a massive resource for young people trying to learn (who incidentally are actually the future...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know which item from the first collection is currently in use. This is simplest done by using a `for`loop.. You can then access the right item from the second collection:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Titles.Count; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Title: {Titles[i].Text}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Article Text: {Text[i].Text}");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should make it a single loop and iterate through both collections.

```
for (var x = 0; x < Math.Max(Titles.Count, Text.Count); x++)
{
  if (Titles.Count > x)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {Titles[x].Text}");
  }
  if (Text.Count > x)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Article Text: {Text[x].Text}");
  }
}
```

Comment: @DavidG OMG, I feel so stupid right now! You are absolutely right. Assumed it to be `Min`because it kind of made sense to me :-D